# Post URL in background without iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a checkout page for our ecommerce site.

Trying to add an option for customers to send us payment through wire-transfer, but I need to automatically add $25 to the order's total to cover fees. I'm trying to do this by adding a product to the shopping cart. This must be done without refreshing the page since refreshing resets some customer selection options (such as shipping etc).

The url that needs to be posted is:

```
'add_cart.asp?quick=1&item_id=16'
```

And currently I"m attempting this with an iframe as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleOnWireTransferFee() {
        if(document.getElementById('offline-42').checked) {
           var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
           iframe.height=1;
           iframe.width=1;
           iframe.seamless;
           iframe.src='add_cart.asp?quick=1&item_id=16';
           document.body.appendChild(iframe);

           // this will refresh the entire page -- bad!
           //window.location='add_cart.asp?quick=1&item_id=16';
        }
    }
</script>
```

This creates a 1 x 1 pixel iframe at the bottom of the page and is pretty much invisible to the customer. It adds the product to the shopping cart and when the customer checks out, they get the grand total they need to wire us.

The problem is this causes the page to jump when it loads the iframe (to put it into focus  however it's 1x1 and pretty much invisible so the customer just gets a weird experience)

Is there a way to prevent this "jump" of the page, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you're trying to do is commonly known as Ajax.  Modern browsers have an object called [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), but more commonly a toolset like jQuery is used, that might look like this:

```
$.ajax{
  url : 'add_cart.asp',
  data : {
    quick : 1,
    itemId : 16
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it as an ajax-style post.  Use $.post (or, better, $.ajax since then you can add error handling)